# ¿Cómo es posible que alguien sin reputación ofrezca una recompensa?

Tags: soporte, reputación, recompensas, privilegios

He visto hoy en SOes alguien sin reputación que ofrece una recompensa de +50 Me pregunto de donde saldrán los +50 para la buena respuesta, si el usuario no logra tener 50 en el plazo de los 6 días.
¿Cómo es posible que el sistema lo permita?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respuesta corta:

**No se puede.** Si el usuario no tiene la reputación para ofrecer esa recompensa no va a poder crearla.

Sobre el caso específico:

Me imagino que hablas sobre [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/13734/7242) dónde el texto que aparece sobre la recompensa dice (fíjate en la parte en negrita):

> Esta pregunta tiene abierta una recompensa por valor de +50 de reputación por parte de **ArtEze** que concluye en 6 días.
>
> Una o más de las respuestas son ejemplares y valen una recompensa adicional.

Por lo que quién ha ofrecido la recompensa no es el autor de la pregunta, que no tiene la reputación necesaria, sino [ArtEze](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/13558/arteze), que sí la tiene.

Recuerda que se pueden ofrecer recompensas sin importar el autor de la pregunta. De ahí sale la medalla [Altruista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/48/altruist).

Comment: Pues tienes razón, disculpa por la pregunta. No entiendo como funciona, ¿alguien puede publicar una pregunta de otro usuario? ¿Y lo hace solo por una medalla?

Comment: No exactamente. No se puede *publicar* una pregunta de otro usuario. Lo que se puede hacer es ofrecer una *recompensa* en la pregunta de otro usuario. El objetivo no es la medalla (que sólo se consigue 1 vez) sino más bien poner un foco de atención en una pregunta que te ha parecido interesante, que necesita atención, que quieres más detalles, que no tiene respuestas y tienes el mismo problema, etc... Si seleccionas ofrecer recompensa en alguna pregunta verás los distintos motivos.

Comment: Gràcies Miquel!

Comment: Marc Lemien... Uuh, vaya confusión generé. Me alegra que ya lo entiendas, quise darle 50 puntos a la respuesta de @PaperBirdMaster, que está tan interesante.